# URL forwarding depending on client

Tags: url, redirect, web, forwarding

Is it possible to use one URL, for example, "www.voucheres.com" and have it forward to:

1. "www.example1.com" when opened on a desktop web browser
2. "www.appstore.com/exampleurl/" when opened on an iOS device
3. "www.playstore.com/exampleurl2/" when opened on an Android device?

So the forwarding should depend on the client (Windows / OSX / iOS / Android)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. How to do it depends on your server.

Comment: @EtienneMiret Care to elaborate? I've got a hosting account on ipage.com and a server running Apache on AWS.They are two different set ups for two different sites.